# using ajax to pass string from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I have a piece of javascript code in an html document that responds to a button click. I want a new url to open, and if I specify the link in javascript as I've done below, everything works fine.

```
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Purchase Module"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("submitbtn").addEventListener("click",handle_click);
function handle_click() {
var link;
link="http://www.google.com";
window.location.href=link;
}
</script>
```

Problem is I want to hide the real link on the server side as it includes a username:password. The php script below calls a function (not shown) that generates the link (a string). This also works fine.

```
<?php
$link=get_page_link();
?>
```

I want to pass the link string to the javascript and have tried various iterations of
`link=<?php echo $link ;?>` to no avail. As I understand it you can't pass strings this way and you need to use ajax. That's where I'm stuck. Seems like I need a $_POST on the php side and a $_GET on the java side, but not sure on the specifics. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try using quotes ie. link=‘<?php echo $link ;?>’

Comment: "Problem is I want to hide the real link on the server side as it includes a username:password." - bad idea. You're just hiding it somewhere else, anybody looking at the network traffic can still get it.

Comment: Yes I've used quotes etc.. with <?php echo... doesn't work.  Regarding security, I just don't want an explicit reference in the javascript, and the link is to a password protected folder.

Comment: I'm thinking ajax as it appears to be the only way to communicate between php and javascript. My question is how do you do it, not should I do it?

Comment: Google "xhr http request tutorial". The idea is to send an HTTP request in the background, from client side (JS) to server side (PHP). As Ajax makes use of the HTTP protocol, you need a URL pointing to a PHP document which generates and sends the HTTP response (the password...) back to client side (JS). When you are done with your Ajax request, copy paste the URL to your browser address bar, and observe there is no difference with a regular web page, and conclude your password is **not secured**.